# Change ImageView image during animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview

I have an `ImageView`. I want to:
1 - shrink the view
2 - change the image resource
3 - scale back the view

I tried to this in the following section of code, but this is not working. It behaves like the 3rd row doesn't exist. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale);
Animation animo = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale_out);
i.startAnimation(anim);
i.setImageResource(R.drawable.logoc);
i.startAnimation(animo);
```

scale.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromXScale="1.0" 
android:toXScale="0.125"
android:fromYScale="1.0" 
android:toYScale="0.125" 
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%" 
android:startOffset="0" 
android:duration="400"
android:fillBefore="true" />
```

scale_out.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromXScale="1.0" 
android:toXScale="4.0"
android:fromYScale="1" 
android:toYScale="4.0" 
android:startOffset="400" 
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:duration="800"
 />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try doing this way:

```
i.startAnimation(anim);
if (anim.hasEnded())
{
    i.setImageResource(R.drawable.logoc);
    i.startAnimation(animo);
}
```

Edit:

Ok, I was wrong: This works:

```
public class MyAnimationListener implements AnimationListener {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            i.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg);
            i.startAnimation(animo);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }
```

---

```
MyAnimationListener mListener = new MyAnimationListener();
        anim.setAnimationListener(mListener);
        i.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: So it straight away changes resource of image and applies second animation?

Comment: No, it straight away the first animation

Comment: @slyder07: Hi, just use i.setAnimation(anim); instead of i.startAnimation(anim);